# unable to qualify only xsd attribute using XJC

Tags: xml, jaxb, xjc

I need to generate my XML like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<advice_request xmlns="urn:xyz.com:bf:api:core:v1" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<instructions>
    <instruction i:type="advice_instruction_adjust">
        <method>not_set</method>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <site_guid>abcd123</site_guid>
    </instruction>
</instructions>
</advice_request>
```

Note the "type" attribute is qualified with "i".

I have defined the xsd as :

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="urn:xyz.com:bf:api:core:v1"
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    targetNamespace="urn:xyz.com:bf:api:core:v1"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">  
<xsd:element name="advice_request">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="instructions" type="Instructions" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:complexType name="Instructions">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="instruction" type="Instruction" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Instruction">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="method" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="quantity" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="site_guid" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="type" id="type" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

The XJC generates the following package-info.java:

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "urn:xyz.com:bf:api:core:v1", elementFormDefault = QUALIFIED)
```

However on marshalling the object I always get the XML as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<advice_request xmlns="urn:xyz.com:bf:api:core:v1">
<instructions>
    <instruction type="advice_instruction_adjust">
        <method>not_set</method>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <site_guid>abcd123</site_guid>
    </instruction>
</instructions>
</advice_request>
```

How do I get the attribute qualified with "i"? Any help greaty appreciated.

I have tried multiple things like importing the XMLSchema-instance namespace, setting the SCHEMA_LOCATION on marshaller explicitly (although this may not be an option to me) but still nothing ...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an Hierarchy for your `complexType`. `i:type="advice_instruction_adjust"` Means that there is a `complextType` called `advice_instruction_adjust`.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="urn:xyz.com:bf:api:core:v1"
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    targetNamespace="urn:xyz.com:bf:api:core:v1"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified">  

    <xsd:element name="advice_instruction_adjust" type="advice_instruction_adjust"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="advice_instruction_adjust">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="Instruction">
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:element name="Instructions" type="Instructions"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="Instructions">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="instruction" type="Instruction" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>


    <xsd:complexType name="Instruction" abstract="true">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="method" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="quantity" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="site_guid" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

[See here more details](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_complextype.asp)

Here an example of XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:Instructions xmlns:ns1="urn:xyz.com:bf:api:core:v1"  xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ns1:instruction i:type="advice_instruction_adjust">
        <ns1:method />
        <ns1:quantity/>
        <ns1:site_guid/>
    </ns1:instruction>
</ns1:Instructions>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir!! I was not familiar with this and was assuming that "type" was an attribute. Appreciate the prompt response.